# how to get the value of tr of a table using jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an example table

```
<table class="table">
  <tr value="1" class="side-link">
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
 <tr value="2" class="side-link">
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the value of the selected tr on click function.
what I've tried so far

```
$(".table").on('click','.side-link',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(id);
});
```

the problem is I cannot address this to the respective "tr" I click , instead it gets the value of `.table`.
Can anyone solve the issue here? I would be really grateful! THanks :)

Note: it needs ( on click ) because I've to replace tr using ajax and the new elements wont be recognized by just using click function !!

Jquery version 1.9.1

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MyuFV/1/

Comment: are you want 'tr' value or all 'td' value inside 'tr'..?

Comment: @HasanAlaca, if you don't want to answer then fine !

Comment: @rid, appreciate your help ! thanks budd

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$(".table").on('click','tr',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(id);
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBE4v/2/)

Comment: i am trying to get the attribute of respective tr ! please read the question carefully

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin Since you mentioned that using ajax you're trying to add new trs.  I have tried the same thing without ajax in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jBE4v/3/

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan, thanks ! i just replaced my class name with tr and it worked fine !

Answer (score 0):

You're (as you say) getting the value of the table, not the TR

Amend your code like this:

```
$(".table tr").on('click','.side-link',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr('value');
alert(id);
});
```

That should get the correct value.

Comment: This is not working http://jsfiddle.net/8ma2N/1/ because `value` is not associated with table

Comment: hey @rid , your code is not working too .. i've tried . thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Your code also working see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jBE4v/1/), check that you have included `jquery version >= 1.7` or try to `write` your code in `$(function(){...})` it may `run` before your `table renders`

You can also try it like,

```
$(function(){
    $(".table .side-link").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jBE4v/)

Also if it is `id` then why you used `value` use `id="1" and so on..`

**Updated** if above not works then try this which never fails(IMHO) if your `html` is `valid`,

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click',".table .side-link",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Comment: hi rohan, it works fine, yes and i know it, the main reason is that when i use ajax, new tr element is placed with new values, then click wont work beacuse it needs on click to work with new elements. Thanks anyways

Comment: i am not a genius as you are , so if you want to help then help !!

Answer (score 0):

well use HTML5 data attribute.. this is the exact reason, why data attribute  was introduce in HTML5. And make sure you are using  jquery's latest version (> 1.6) `.on` was introduced 
only after jquery 1.6

**HTML**

```
 <table class="table">
   <tr data-value="1" class="side-link">
     <td>one</td>
     <td>two</td>
   </tr>
 <tr data-value="2" class="side-link">
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".table").on('click','.side-link',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data('value');
  alert(id);
});
```

Comment: i do not want the value of table, i meant of tr,.. what i've done is wrong , i want the attribute of tr !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, look this for get Tr value or Td value:

**HTML Code:**

```
<table class="table" border='1'>
    <tr value="1" class="side-link">
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr value="2" class="side-link">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(".table").on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var trValue = $(this).attr('value');
    var tdValue = $(this).children('td').map(function (index, val) {
            return $(this).text();
        }).toArray();
        // all td value with comma seprated
    alert(tdValue);
    // current tr attr value
    alert(trValue);
});
```

**[Live Demo (JsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/3LDMK/)**